# Joining two table with condition

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables.

1. **parent table**: contains pid, pname and gender columns
2. **child table** : *child_parent* table contains childid and parent id

I need final out put as:

```
childid, parentid, fathername, mothername (based on gender value)
```

I am new to SQL.

I have written below query, but I am not getting the expected results:

```
select 
    cc.cpid, p.pid, p.pname,
    case p.gender 
        when 'M' then 'father'
        when 'F' then 'Mother'
    end as Parenttype
from 
    parent p
join 
    child_parent cc on (cc.pid = p.pid) 
order by 
    cc.cpid
```

Comment: Start from child, join parents twice :)

Comment: I think the data is not sufficient. There should be 2 Parent Id's in the Child Table? What are those columns in the Child Table?

Comment: chld contains cid and pid ex:cid 1 contain 2,5 one for mother another for fater those are pid in parent table also

Comment: What are those exact column names for 2, 5?

Comment: child table contains only 2 column cid and pid

Comment: 2 and 5 is pid value

Comment: Is it `1` and `2,5` **comma** separated Idn's for parent? Comm separated is a bad design, you need to normalize it then or use some hacks to join it.

Comment: it is not comma separated child 1 have two entry in table one row contian 1(cid) pid(2) and second row cid(1) and pid(5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the problems you have is that you have a separate row for each parent relationship. If you want to combine this into one row (with separate columns for each parent), you'll have to use aggregation.

As @Venkataraman_R noted, you can join the `Child` table to your `Parent` table twice (once for the father, and once for the mother). Then you can use an aggregate function to "fold" the rows into 1:

```
SELECT
    child_parent.cid,
    father_id = MIN(Father.pid),
    father_name = MIN(Father.pname),
    mother_id = MIN(Mother.pid),
    mother_name = MIN(Mother.pname)
FROM child_parent
    LEFT JOIN parent AS Father ON
        Father.pid = child_parent.pid
        AND Father.gender = 'M'
    LEFT JOIN parent as Mother ON
        Mother.pid = child_parent.pid
        AND Mother.gender = 'F'
GROUP BY child_parent.cid
```

Notice how I give the parent table meaningful aliases each time, just like @Venkataraman_R.

With the aggregate functions, you now have one row:

```
+-----+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| cid | father_id | father_name | mother_id | mother_name |
+-----+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
|   1 |         2 | Jack        |         3 | Josephine   |
+-----+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Now, a word of caution: This query assumes that each child will have at most one father, and at most one mother. What about children with 2 mothers or 2 fathers (or more, in cases of polygamy)? Also, with single-parent households, you'll need to handle cases where one of the columns will be null.

Also, depending on what you're modeling, you may need to consider cases where a parent's gender is neither 'M' or 'F'.

I have a fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/unPgavPquPwqNMMUGtLeWN/0). It's Postgres, but the syntax is about the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can write conditional join using additional condition, as given below:

```
 select cc.cpid,p.pid, f.pname as father_name, m.pname as mother_name    
        from child_parent AS cc 
        join parent AS f on cc.pid=f.pid and gender = 'M'
        join parent AS m on cc.pid=m.pid and gender = 'F'             
        order by cc.cpid
```

Comment: You don't need to use sub-queries...just list the 2nd condition in your `ON` clause...

Comment: @Zack, simplified the query, as you suggested. thanks.

Comment: hi thank for the replay but it's giving empty result set